# How to findparent div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an html like this .When I click on a li, I need to add a class like to my parent div.SO outer div becomes `<div class="as new">`.I have tried following code but doesn't add class

```
$('ul').parent('div').addClass('new');

<div class="as">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger cookieul">Set favourite</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="caret"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>

  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" id="jq">
    <li><a href="#">jquery<span id="d">del</span></a></li>


  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you show more context? Are you running your code in the `<head>` section, in a DOM-ready event handler, etc.?

Comment: wrap your code in ready handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this at **document.ready**

```
$('li').on('click', function(){
   $(this).closest('div').addClass('new');

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('ul.dropdown-menu li').click(function(){
       $(this).parent().parent().addClass('new');

   });
}) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this code and it works:

```
$('li').click(function(){
    $(this).parents("div:first").addClass('new');
});
```